# Git pull in Powershell and how to get the output of a command

Tags: ssh, powershell, git, debug

I am pretty new to using PowerShell for automation. 
I want to ssh into a machine, and run a git pull in it. This works when I do it through the powershell manually, but not when I automate it through the code. What I have is:

```
$Password = "mypsw"
$User = "myusername"
$ComputerName = "computername"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

$SessionID = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credentials 

#$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command "ls"
$result.Output # this one works as expected, returns the list of folders and files
$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index $sessionid.sessionid -Command "git pull"
$result.Output # this doesn't return anything
```

If I don't save the $result value, I get

```
Host       : [myhost]
Output     : {}
ExitStatus : 128
```

which is pointing to an error message. However I will never be able to debug it if I don't know exactly what the output of the console is. 
So I guess I have two problems here.

1) How to get the real output of the remote console in my shell

2) How to make git pull work

And a general question:

Is PowerShell the right tool for automating these tasks, or should I use something different?
Thanks

Comment: I would recommend having your script send all of its output to a log file. Then you should be able to see the exact error messages in the log.

Comment: I have done everything using putty and plink. No reason to complicate my life :)